# How to convert javascript funtion with spread arg in differ types to c# style?

Tags: c#, typescript, arguments

I am struggling with the strikt typing of c# by the function arguments.

For my RPN calculator, the needed arguments will be submitted by a function call with a comma separated argument list of differ types:

```
this.FxMath. RPN(this.Mt, this.L, 2, '*', this.F, '*')   // This.Mt are Variables as Objects)
```

The function itself will get the comma separated argument as ...seq:

```
RPN(ergebnis: VariableUnitBuilder, ...seq: any) {
```

as:

```
RPN(ergebnis: VariableUnitBuilder, ...seq: any) {

    let stack = [], i = 0;

    typeof seq[i] === 'object' ? seq[i] = seq[i].nominalValue : null;
    stack.push(seq[i]);
    i++;

    while (i <= seq.length) {

      typeof seq[i] === 'object' ? seq[i] = seq[i].nominalValue : null; // Zahlenwert extraieren oder nix.
      let item = seq[i];  // Number or operator

      if (isNaN(item)) {
        let a: number;
        let b: number;

        switch (item) {
          case '+':
            a = parseFloat(stack.pop());
            b = parseFloat(stack.pop());
            stack.push(a + b);

            break; 
...... }
```

Now I have to need some arguments with differ types and unknown length:

(this.Mt, this.L, 2.5, '*', this.F, '*') // Class, Class, Double , String, Class, String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`params` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters#params-modifier) wich allows a method to accept a variable number of parameters and combine it with array of `System.Object`:

```
public void RPN(VariableUnitBuilder p, params object[] seq)
{
   // ...
}
```

And calls looking like:

```
someInstance.RPN(someVariableUnitBuilder, 1, "2");
someInstance.RPN(someVariableUnitBuilder, 1, "2", 3, new object());
```

Note that for [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) this will result in [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) which can be undesirable.